# PHP Soap - Error Fetching http headers when sending long XML string

Tags: php, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

as I've described my issue in the title. I'm working with SoapClient in PHP to call my method in WCF Service WSDL. When I send my XML string which has under 3 elements it work properly. But when I send a XML string which contains more than 5 elements it return Error. I guess this issue caused by the size of String i'm trying to post. I've tried to configure some parameters but it didn't make any sense. Moreover, I pretty sure that my WCF Service still working well with large XML string after Testing with SOAPUI and WcfTestClient tool.

> Hence some parameters I've already tried according to lots of topic on the internet with Soap option but it still failed.
>   Hence my code:
>   [My SoapClient call](http://pastebin.com/mXdASUwz)

Hence my ComplexType which xmlDOMAIN is my XML string:
[image: WCF ComplexType]

Comment: What is your question? What is your php code looking like? What says the error you get?

Comment: for clearly, I'm trying to post a long XML string to my WCF service but it throw Exception Error Fetching Http headers

Comment: Okay I got it now.

Comment: @Marcel Do you have any idea? I've tried to config php.ini but it doesn't make any sense, too